# Laravel Forge deploy error GitHub token is invalid

Tags: laravel, forge

I got

```
We were unable to enable quick deploy for your site because your GitHub token 
is invalid for this repository or has expired. Please refresh the token in
your Forge account profile's "Authentication" tab.
```

I did what it says but did not help.

Below is my Deploy Script:

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force
```

I ran it manually on server, I got

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr
  ement primary key, `email` varchar(255) not null, `first_name` varchar(50)
  not null, `last_name` varchar(50) not null, `organization` varchar(255) not
   null, `reason` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(60) not null, `ro
  le` varchar(255) not null default 'reg', `activation_code` varchar(255) not
   null, `status` tinyint not null default '0', `remember_token` varchar(100)
   null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp de
  fault 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists
```

I commented out table creating script and still can not using Quick Deploy.

Comment: What happens if you SSH into the server and pull the project yourself?

Comment: Pull works fine. Artisan Migrate also works now since I'm not creating tables.

Comment: what about the composer install command?

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm talking about you in the terminal yourself, not using the Forge deploy UI.

Comment: In SSH TERMINAL, not forge

Comment: So what happens if you run `composer update` ?

Comment: forge@colorful-canopy:~/default$ composer update
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime                                                                                                  performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed

Comment: killed when I run `composer update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108003/discussion-between-daolincheng-and-oliver-queen).

Comment: Did you find a resolution in the end? I'm having the same issue with one of my Forge sites.

Comment: @JoeSpurling No, I restored everything from backup.

Answer (score 0):

We got this error when we renamed our repo. We had to Click the scary red button in Forge that says "Uninstall Repository" (we also ticked roll back migrations). Then we could specify the new repo name and activate Quick Deploy. The whole process took literally two minutes and our site was back up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that - as I was working with a new release on a staging environment - I had changed the deployment branch to a release branch. And as that was different from the one I was pulling in the deployment script, for some reason it produced the above error. Matching the two branches did fix the issue straight away.